# Remote Debugging with Squish IDE

Tags: testing, ide, remote-debugging, squish, gui-test-framework

I want to do remote debugging of Squish application.

I am following document at:
http://kb.froglogic.com/display/KB/Configuring+a+remote+squishserver
for the same.

Step 1 and Step 2 went well, even I able to see the logs in terminal from remote application.

But, the debug point is not hitting in Squish IDE. Even the debug view shows nothing though I have done the exact steps given at Step 3, even restart of Squish IDE didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not Squish stops at a breakpoint (I suppose that's what you meant when you wrote "debug point") is independant of where the `squishserver` process is running. You can verify that the remote server is used simply by launching a test: you should see some output in the console where `squishserver` is started about incoming network connections.

Comment: Actually I want to debug the script. How can I do it, if it doesn't stop at break point.

Comment: @Abhinav If you notice that it doesn't stop at a break point, did you verify that the control flow executes the line at all? E.g. if you put a `test.log` statement right before the line on which you put the breakpoint, can you see that debug output? I suspect this issue is unrelated to whether you have Squish connect to a remote server or not.

Comment: Yes the `test.log` is logging. Even while locally running the break point is being hit. In my case the test are running as part of Jenkin Job which is failing somehow and I want to debug to find where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When running squish remotely you could add the flag: "--reportgen xml3.3,xml3report" This will create a report with all the information about your run. You can then import this report into squshIDE and use "vpdiff" tool to analyze your failure.

There is a command line tool called "vpdiff" which comes in SQUISHDIR/bin.
There is an article about it here:
https://www.froglogic.com/blog/analysing-test-reports-from-automated-executions-using-the-squish-ide/